# Cannot read property 'watch' of undefined in gulp

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

Can some one help please? I keep recieving this error and I really dont know what else to do. When I trigger the command `gulp watch` in the cmd, I receive the following error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'watch' of undefined`

> ```
> C:\Apache24\htdocs\Gulp>gulp watch
> [10:37:07] Using gulpfile C:\Apache24\htdocs\Gulp\gulpfile.js
> [10:37:07] Starting 'watch'...
> [10:37:07] 'watch' errored after 4.16 ms
> [10:37:07] TypeError: Cannot read property 'watch' of undefined
>    at watch (C:\Apache24\htdocs\Gulp\gulpfile.js:42:10)
>    at watch (C:\Apache24\htdocs\Gulp\node_modules\undertaker\lib\set-task.js:13:15)
>    at bound (domain.js:422:14)
>    at runBound (domain.js:435:12)
>    at asyncRunner (C:\Apache24\htdocs\Gulp\node_modules\async-done\index.js:55:18)
>    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:75:11)
> ```

```
const {src, dest, series, gulp, parallel} = require('gulp');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');
var sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');

var styleSRC = './src/scss/style.scss';
var styleDIST = './dist/css/';


var jsSRC = './src/js/script.js';
var jsDIST = './dist/js/';


function style() {
    "use strict";
    return src(styleSRC)
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(sass({
            errorLogToConsole: true,
            outputStyle: 'compressed'
        }))
        .on('error', console.error.bind(console))
        .pipe(autoprefixer({
            overrideBrowserslist: ["defaults"],
            cascade: false
        }))
        .pipe(rename({basename: 'style', suffix: '.min'}))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./'))
        .pipe(dest(styleDIST));
}


function js() {
    "use strict";
    return src(jsSRC)
        .pipe(dest(jsDIST));
}

const watch = function () {
    "use strict";
    gulp.watch('./src/scss/**/*.scss', {usePolling: true}, gulp.series(style));
    gulp.watch('./src/js/**/*.js', {usePolling: true}, gulp.series(js));
};
exports.default = series(
    parallel(style, js),
    watch
);

exports.watch = watch;
exports.js = js;
exports.style = style;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have got your destructuring a bit wrong. You have:

```js
const {src, dest, series, gulp, parallel} = require('gulp');
//                          ^ this does not exist - hence the undefined property
```

I think you want to replace the `gulp` in the destructuring with `watch`, so it's now:

```js
const {src, dest, series, watch, parallel} = require('gulp');
```

and in your `watch` function do:

```js
// renamed the function to avoid conflict
const watchTask = function () {
    "use strict";
    watch('./src/scss/**/*.scss', {usePolling: true}, series(style));
    watch('./src/js/**/*.js', {usePolling: true}, series(js));
};

exports.default = series(
    parallel(style, js),
    watchTask
);

exports.watch = watchTask;
```

Comment: first of all thanks for the response, but with this method i receive a redefinition of "watch" error because i am declaring watch as a const in the first line already

Comment: @ANDREWEBARE - aaah, yes, of course, because your function name is also called `watch` - I suppose you could just rename the function, the call in the `default`, and the assignment in the `export`...?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, remove const and define it as a function.

```
function watch() {
    "use strict";
    gulp.watch('./src/scss/**/*.scss', {usePolling: true}, gulp.series(style));
    gulp.watch('./src/js/**/*.js', {usePolling: true}, gulp.series(js));
};
```

Comment: thanks for the response, i tried this method and i recieve a redefinition of "watch" error.